# How to return data in a more simplified manner from a jagged array?

Tags: c#

I've created a factory class which allows the user to call a method `Generate` and it populates a jagged array via some logic that generally I don't want the user to deal with.

A lot of index's are null because of the type of grid layout that the factory generates.

But I don't want the user to have to iterate both array indexes and check for null. Is there anyway to simplify this for a user to iterate this array without them needing to worry about it.

For example, to iterate the data they currently have to do:

```
for (int i = Map.MapData.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    for (int j = Map.MapData[i].Length - 1; j >= 0; --j)
    {
         // would rather they didn't have to check for null
         if (Map.MapData[i][j] == null) continue;

         // do stuff with data
    }
}
```

This isn't all that user friendly. Is there a way I can make the data be more linear to the user, like using a for each on the data? I'm not entirely sure what I am looking for in order to achieve this, hope some one can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Does the user need the array indices? Is it ok to just iterate through the non-null elements (like a foreach loop)?

Comment: Skipping the null would be better since then they don't have to worry about nulls.

Comment: How about converting that to a list like List<int> list = jaggedArray.SelectMany(T => T).ToList();
Use it to check for null, and with a single for loop. With two for loops the time complexity in your case may be O(n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to loop through the elements of the array and discard the indices, you can do an extension method:

```
public static class JaggedArrayExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> IterateNonNull<T>(this T[][] array) where T : class {
        for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            for (int j = array[i].Length - 1; j >= 0; --j)
            {
                // would rather they didn't have to check for null
                if (array[i][j] == null) continue;

                yield return array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can loop through your jagged array with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in jaggedArray.IterateNonNull()) {
    // ...
}
```

If this is the first you see `yield return`, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield).

Comment: Oh nice, so thats how you do it. This was not easy to find on Microsoft's website. Thanks for the code example :)

Comment: @WDUK If this is the first time you've seen `yield`, this link might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: I've used yield for coroutines for example. Just did not know how to use a jagged array as a for each.

Comment: Just a follow up question, is it possible to do this without calling the method, so it is automatic? I've seen some for each loops where you don't have data.Method it just has data. Does it use default if you don't specify or something?

Comment: @WDUK Those are possible because the thing that is being looped through implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Jagged arrays probably implements that as well, so you can say `foreach(var item in jaggedArray)`, but that does not skip the nulls.

Answer (score 2):

When *querying* collections (in your case you want all not `null` items) try using *Linq*:

```
  var NotNullItems = Map
    .SelectMany(line => line      // From each line
       .Where(x => x != null));   // Filter out all null items

  foreach (var item in NotNullItems) {
    // do stuff with data
  }
```